# raspicam c++ library

Tags: raspicam, c++

can you give me a tutorial like video or anything about how to use raspicam library...?
i follow this url
https://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40
but still don't get it

[image: error list]

Answer (score 0):

You have illegal characters on line 10 or the end of line 9. These most likely came from copying and pasting. The easiest way to correct the problem is to retype (do not copy and paste, and don't use and keyboard macros like <kbd>shift-space</kbd>) line 10 and line 9 if required.

More info on the causes and possible solutions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311672/error-stray-240-in-program) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167656/error-stray-302-in-program).

As for tutorials certainly your Google foo is as good as anyone elses here. You may also want to look at the Python code which may be clearer.